# Elastisearch Query to filter out values in column based on another column

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm working with a dataset that I'm trying to filter, but I'm having trouble trying to get the results I want, and I'm not sure it's possible to do so.  Some sample data is below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| good | awe | 1 | 9834 |
| great | niopre | 1 | 78964 |
| bad | nue | 1 | 12 |
| good | btr | 2 | 6543 |
| great | muy | 2 | 8765 |
| bad | xdrg | 2 | 1432 |
| bad | thr | 3 | 648 |
| good | cfg | 3 | 6 |
| bad | mk | 3 | 1958 |

What I want to do is use Column A and C in the filter and only show the values in Column C that also have a row that includes "great" in Column A. So for this dataset the filter would return:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| good | awe | 1 | 9834 |
| great | niopre | 1 | 78964 |
| bad | nue | 1 | 12 |
| good | btr | 2 | 6543 |
| great | muy | 2 | 8765 |
| bad | xdrg | 2 | 1432 |

I've tried through the built in filters and through the Elasticsearch Query DSL and haven't had any luck yet.  If anyone can help guide me in the right direction on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome @djervis ! Are you searching for the Kibana query (KQL)?

Comment: First of all, do not think of any "columns" or "rows" here, that's a different type of database, it's nothing like classic relational, nor columnar. Think documents - that's the entity it operates. Hence all the filters and conditions are evaluated against a document in storage, and then it moves over to next one and repeats. What you want is to evaluate the condition based on whether _another_ document does exist in this index that matches certain criteria (have same C & A=great). Correct?

Comment: @djervis can you please explain your use case more clearly ?